# Wordpress post by e-mail categorization tagging plugin?

Tags: wordpress

Is there a plugin for wordpress that will parse a post-by-email post and assign it categories/tags automagically?

Answer (score 1):

The Postie plugin will allow you to specify categories and tags in your email.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/postie/

Comment: This looks like a great plug-in, but not exactly what I was looking for. I don't want the person e-mailing the posts to have to decide what they should be tagged/categorized as...